# SAS Join Not Matching Character Variables

Tags: character-encoding, sas

I am joining two tables by character fields which contain five digits but I'm matching on only about 20 records out of 6,000.

An example of a non-match is the first table shows a value of '09813' but no match is found; yet manually querying the second table for a value of '09813' yields a result.  (This seems to indicate an issue with the value in the first table...)  I've also noted some anomalies where '7144' seems to be matching to '7144D' but manually retrieving '7144' in the second table doesn't match, but '07144' retrieved the correct match.

I've tried converting the value in the first table to Hex and there doesn't seem to be any additional characters aside from the empty spaces (20) added to the end due to the length of the hex conversion.  I also tried adding strip(compress([Field Name],,'kw')) to the join statement and a few other variations to try to remove line breaks, etc., but haven't had any luck thus far.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show your code and data, preferably with examples that illustrate the issue as per [ask]. If you can make a small reproducible example that would be great. Usually these issues mean that your join condition isn't correct or you're not removing leading spaces or invisible characters which are rare but occur if you're moving data between OSs and various systems.

Comment: Looks a lot like something has converted your field from character to numeric.  That would explain the missing leading zero. Have you transported the data as text files?  If so have you let PROC IMPORT or Excel guess how to interpret the text files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the incorrect join field, thank you for the help!